# BDD newbie ... heroku addon - stillalive is not pressing button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, bdd

I want to impliment BDD with [stillalive](http://stillalive.com) addon of heroku for http://designer.mobdis.biz

But I facing the problem with `When I press "person_submit"` for

```
<input id="person_submit" name="commit" type="button" value="Login" class="loginLargeButton">
```

without input any email and password. It should show

> Password is not valid

which it isn't. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your LOGIN button to type='submit' from type='button' then when you click it you'll see the message;

"You did not provide any details for authentication."

That may work better for you in your stillalive tests.

UPDATE: Although I think the problem maybe the javascript that you're using for handling the click is what your problem is as I don't think StillAlive etc will be handling/executing/reading the javascripts.

Comment: so my option is to use cucumber gem with guard instead of still alive?

Comment: it may make sense to handle cases where javascript is disabled so you can still test from stillalive - so you would need to implement server side validations.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried that manually on your site and nothing happened. (Safari 5.0.5 for Mac).

Answer (score 1):

FWIW [StillAlive.com](https://stillalive.com/) now has fully Javascript capable workers.  So the above Javascript based login form should work fine.